# Laravel 5.1 product url with id and .html

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5

Is it possible to catch parts of url i Laravel routes ?
For example :

```
 .com/product-name-101.html
```

It's link for product with id 101.

This is what I try to do:

```
Route::get('/(:any)-{id}.html', function($id) {
    return $id;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a regex route. Here's something that should work:

```
Route::get('{name}-{id}.html', function ($name, $id) {
  $name = trim($name,'-'); // remove any trailing dashes from the name
})->where(['id' => '[0-9]+', 'name' => '[^0-9\.]+']);
```

Comment: Thank you, this has opened my eyes ;-)